# Get info about Windows 7 theme using MFC in VC++

Tags: windows, visual-c++, mfc

Situation -- 
I have to do something in an MFC based application, if the windows (Windows 7) machine has the Hight Contrast (1/2) applied.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would typically call [SystemParametersInfo()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724947.aspx) and pass it a [HIGHCONTRAST](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318112.aspx) structure:

```
HIGHCONTRAST highContrast;
ZeroMemory(&highContrast, sizeof(HIGHCONTRAST));
highContrast.cbSize = sizeof(HIGHCONTRAST);
SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETHIGHCONTRAST, sizeof(HIGHCONTRAST),
    &highContrast, 0);
```

If high contrast is enabled, the `dwFlags` member of the `HIGHCONTRAST` structure will have its `HCF_HIGHCONTRASTON` bit set to `1` upon return.